# Click on first not working in android code

Tags: android

Thanks in Advance. Help me out in this situation. Problem is first click on button does not work but after clicks works fine so I am in weird situation How it is made as first click view?. code is below
    Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:background="#CDCDCD" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="user_account_creation"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#252525" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#252525" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#252525" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#252525" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="More" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main class method

```
       @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (btn.getText()=="More") {
                btn.setText("Less"); tl.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE); 
            } 
            else
            { 
                btn.setText("More"); tl.setVisibility(v.GONE);  
            }
        }
    });
}
```

give me the solutions.

Comment: You cannot compare `String` values with `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with equalsIgnoreCase Like this to be more precise 
    `if (btn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("More")) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 if (btn.getText()=="More") {...}
```

to this:

```
 if (btn.getText().toString().equals("More")) {...}
```